# Create a dictionary based on the typename in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a `Type` variable - 
`Type t = typeof(myClass);`

How can I create a Dictionary -
`Dictionary<String, myClass>` using the type variable t?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, it does. Marking my question as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Activator.CreateInstance with a generic-made type:

```
var genType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGeneric(typeof(string), t);
var dictionary = Activator.CreateInstance(genType);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Exactly what I was looking for.